# Find any kind of grammar for the language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata, formal-grammars

> Find any kind of grammar for the language `L = {w ∈ Σ* | in w there
>   are twice as many a's than b's}` and reason its correctness.

Where `w` means word and `Σ` means alphabet, in this case obviously made up of `a,b`.

So I imagine I can build a NFA for the language and then "transform" that NFA into a regular grammar.

A NFA for that language should look like that:

[image]

The regular grammar is `G = ({A,B,C}, {a,b}, P, A)`

```
P : A → aB, ε (where ε is the empty word)
    B → bC
    C → aA
```

How would you show the correctness of that grammar though? I think it's not sufficient to say that the NFA terminates if and only if you start reading an `a`, then a `b` and end with an `a`, all that in a loop. Thus twice as many `a`'s than `b`'s.

Is it correct like that and is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: What about $aab$. Or $aaaabb$?

Comment: @HendrikJan Oh no.. I totally forgot about that :P Thank you! Anyway, if I got it correct till here, how can you show the correctness? I think I need to show that the automata and grammar are equivalent?

Comment: The language isn't regular.